# AWS Amplify Console does not build Nuxt project - creates blank screens in Verify step

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-amplify, nuxt.js, devops-services

I am trying to publish a Nuxt project onto Amplify via the console but when I trigger a build I get all green check marks but the Verify screenshots are all blank and when I try to go to the app url I just keep getting redirected (I think because of redirects for a 404?) until the page breaks.

So I cannot test if the Nuxt project is actually being built but the fact that all the Verify screenshots are blank leads me to believe something is wrong.

My build directions:

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .nuxt
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue with deploying dotfiles (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/278) - should be fixed now if you can give it another try